# Pegar a imagem de um post WordPress desde um arquivo externo

Tags: wordpress, imagem, post

Tenho os títulos dos meus últimos posts, porém eu preciso também buscar e exibir as imagens junto com o título. Este é um arquivo fora da pasta do WordPress, uma página estática que fiz em HTML e CSS:

```
<?php

include('esenergy/wp-load.php'); // Blog path

// Get the last 5 posts
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => 4,
  'category' => 0,
  'orderby' => 'post_date',
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'post_status' => 'publish'
));

// Display them as list
echo '<ul>';
foreach($recent_posts as $post) {
  echo '<li><a href="', get_permalink($post['ID']), '">', $post['post_title'], '</a></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Estou tentando fazer algo assim:

[image]

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/

Comment: Fiz um upgrade na pergunta e resposta, votei +1 na resposta por causa da minha edição, o voto anterior não era meu ;) PS: eu resolveria este problema tentando uma solução parecida com esta: [*How to get WordPress posts from a single category using XML-RPC*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25507463/1287812), é tipo fácil adaptar. Outro link de interesse: [*When should you use WP_Query vs query_posts() vs get_posts()?*](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achei como se fazer usando a classe [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/) e a função [`the_post_thumbnail`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/):

```
<ul>
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
include('esenergy/wp-load.php'); // Blog path
function recentPosts() {
    $rPosts = new WP_Query();
    $rPosts->query('showposts=3');
        while ($rPosts->have_posts()) : $rPosts->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('recent-thumbnails'); ?></a>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h2>
            </li>   
        <?php endwhile; 
    wp_reset_query();
}
?>
</ul>
<?php echo recentPosts(); ?>
```

Comment: Oi, Caio, tomei a liberdade de acrescentar qual é exatamente a solução (WP_Query e the_post_thumbnail) e também de adicionar a linha do `WP_USE_THEMES`. Essa linha é importante porque carrega só o fundamental do WP, se usar o `wp-load.php` puro ele carrega o WP inteiro. Achei melhor porque se alguém copiar este código pelo menos copia certinho.

Comment: PS2: se achou a solução por conta da [dica do Caio Felipe Pereira](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/110348/pegar-a-imagem-de-um-post-wordpress-desde-um-arquivo-externo#comment228978_110348), é legal colocar o crédito na resposta (e depois pode sinalizar este comentário como "obsoleto". Valeu!